# How to connect ASD bios chip

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit

In my little box full of various electronic components I've found an AMIBIOS chip from 1995. The actual chip data are the following:
**Vendor**: ASD
**Number**: AE29F2008-12
**Another number**: 9846
[image: American Megatrends Amibios - AE29F2008-12]

I want to connect this chip to the Arduino and play with it. I'd like to turn it into permanent memory for some small variables like time or current process step.
Because my search for a datasheet was unsuccessful, I now hope there is some general rule to how 32 pin bios chips are supposed to be connected. Is there any? If not, what are the steps I should take to find out what pin does what?
If you know something about my specific chip, please post in comments.

Comment: While a reasonable question something to note is that you'll need to connect most of those pins to your Arduino for it to work and address the full memory area. Probably over 25 pins will need to go to I/O lines as opposed to a modern SPI equivalent that might need more like 3-4 lines.

Comment: Damn, I hoped that some sort of serial communication applies for the chip. I have a  pin arduino, so some additional multiplexing circuitry will be necessary.

Comment: While it might be an interesting for fun / educational excercise (go for it if so) an SPI device that size will cost something like a dollar and less than all the multiplexing circuitry.

Comment: Once I'll want memory storage for practical purposes, I'll probably go for SD card or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [it's a](http://www.flashrom.org/pipermail/flashrom/2010-May/003261.html) [Winbond W29C020C](http://www.gaw.ru/pdf/Winbond/w29c020c.pdf).

Comment: I just realized that there's a '© 1995' sticker.

Comment: Mu main concern was some general rule for bios chipsets (asuming there is one) rather than specific chip info, but thank you anyway.